# Spawning multiple workers with unicorn

Tags: ruby, sinatra, unicorn

I am trying to spawn 7 worker threads using unicorn and my settings are as follows

```
worker_processes 7
timeout 30     
preload_app true
```

But in the logs, I only see one worker spawning. Is there something that I am missing?

```
I, [2014-04-27T01:59:02.190520 #47057]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:9393 fd=7
I, [2014-04-27T01:59:02.190743 #47057]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2014-04-27T01:59:02.191937 #47057]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2014-04-27T01:59:02.192275 #47059]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=47059
I, [2014-04-27T01:59:02.192493 #47059]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2014-04-27T01:59:02.292342 #47628]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Wow, I misread the question's title and had to laugh really hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was under the assumption that unicorn picks up the config file automatically from the config folder. But I had to pass the config file manually using the -c option. Once I passed in the config file, I could see 7 workers being spawned.